# Get values of Enum fields from Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, enums

I have a model with an enum column, e.g.

```py
# Using Django 2.2 (does not support Enums natively)
from django_enum_choices.fields import EnumChoiceField

class Service(Enum)
    MOBILE: "MOBILE"
    LAPTOP: "LAPTOP"


class Device(models.Model):
    service = EnumChoiceField(Service)
    ...
```

Is it possible to get get the query results with the enumerated column being the value of the enum?

For example:
If I do:

```py
query = Device.objects.values("service")
print(query)
```

I get: `<QuerySet [{'service': <Service.MOBILE: 'MOBILE'>}, {'service': <Service.MOBILE: 'MOBILE'>}, {'service': <Service.LAPTOP: 'LAPTOP'>}]>`

I wish to get:
`<QuerySet [{'service': 'MOBILE'}, {'service': 'MOBILE'}, {'service': 'LAPTOP'}]>`

I get errors when I run:
`query = Device.objects.values("service__value")` or `query = Device.objects.values("service.value")`

I want to something like how we can get value of an enum field by saying

```py
mobile_service = Service.MOBILE # <Service.MOBILE: "MOBILE">
mobile_service_as_string = mobile_service.value # "MOBILE"
```

The errors:

1. `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'value' into field. Join on 'service' not permitted.`
2. `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'service.value' into field. Choices are: service, ..`

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Django natively supports enum choices for model fields since version 3

Comment: I'm using Django 2.2 due to legacy reasons, hence the enum plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can just use a serializer!

```py
from django_enum_choices.serializers import EnumChoiceModelSerializerMixin
from rest_framework import serializer


class DeviceSerializer(EnumChoiceModelSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            "service",
        )
```

Results:

```py
query = Device.objects.values("service").all()
results = DeviceSerializer(query, many=True)
print(results)

# [OrderedDict([('service', 'MOBILE')]), OrderedDict([('service', 'LAPTOP')])]
```